# I couldn't open the database file for BibDesk

Tags: bibtex, warnings, bibdesk

I have searched through many posts that address this problem, however, none of the solutions seem to be a fix. I am trying to compile my latex document using BibDesk on a 10.10.3 macbook but the citations only return a question mark (which seems to be a common problem). The document used to compile fine, but now (5 months later) it does not for some odd reason. I have put the .tex file in the same folder as my .bib file, I have compiled

> LaTeX BibTeX LaTeX LaTeX

But I just can't seem to get it to work. My code is below:

```
\usepackage{natbib,setspace}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

Content... \cite{chechulin2014predicting}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014)
The top-level auxiliary file: my - file.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file mybib.bib
---line 27 of file my - file.aux
: \bibdata{mybib
:               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file my - file.aux
:
:
:
```

The name of my bibliography file in BibDesk is mybib.bib, so I'm pretty confident spelling isn't an issue. If anybody has any other suggestions for how I can fix this problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `blg` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally came to a solution. When I had `\bibliography{mybib}`, the bibliography file could not be found. By specifying the location as I did below solves the problem.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{/Users/SextonEconomics/Desktop/mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would you do if there were a space in the file path? Like: \bibliography{/Users/Sexton Economics/Desktop/mybib}

Comment: Is there no way to tell LaTeX to lookup the .bib file in the same directory like the .tex file?